# Symfony2 translation yaml array and twig loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig, yaml

I am trying to have twig convert an array from the translation file

// messages.en.yml

```
termsAndConditions:
  title: Terms and Conditions
  paragraph:
    - Paragraph text...blah blah...1
    - Paragraph text...blah blah...2
    - Paragraph text...blah blah...3
    - Paragraph text...blah blah...n
```

// termsandconditions.html.twig

// tried...

```
{% for i in range(1,termsAndConditions.paragraph|length) -%}
    <p>{% trans %}termsAndConditions.paragraph. {{ i }}{% endtrans %}</p>
{%- endfor %}
```

// and tried...

```
{% for i in range(1,termsAndConditions.paragraph|length) -%}
   <p>{{ 'termsAndConditions.paragraph.' ~ i ~ |trans }}</p>
{%- endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use pairs of `keys: values` to get things to work:

```
// messages.en.yml
termsAndConditions:
  title: Terms and Conditions
  paragraph:
    1: Paragraph text...blah blah...1
    2: Paragraph text...blah blah...2
    3: Paragraph text...blah blah...3
    4: Paragraph text...blah blah...n
```

Also and due to the fact that you want to use a variable for your translation, access to the translation this way `{{('termsAndConditions.paragraph.'~i)|trans }}`.

I've hardcoded 4 instead of `termsAndConditions.paragraph|length`. Not really sure if you can access that from a twig template...

```
// termsandconditions.html.twig
{% for i in range(1,4) -%}
   <p>{{('termsAndConditions.paragraph.'~i)|trans}}</p>
{%- endfor %}
```

It should work. Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

`termsAndConditions.paragraph|length` makes no sense unless you've defined in the template the variable or you've injected the variable through the controller.

**Solutions**

*Solution 1.* In your controller, access the yaml and get the number of translations, then pass it to the template and that's it.

*Solution 2.* Create a service and inject the `translator` service to it. In the controller create a method that calculates the number of elements of a particular `key`. Injecting the translator service is better than reading the yaml directly as it caches the catalogue when it reads it.

*Solution 3.* Same as 2 but creating a twig filter. I'm going to go for this one as it seems kind of fun.

**Solution 3**

Let's start by creating the Extension:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension;

class TransLengthExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct($translator) {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }


    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('translength', array($this, 'translengthFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function translengthFilter($id, $domain = null)
    {
        if (null === $domain) {
            $domain = 'messages';
        }

        $i = 0;
        $g = $this->translator->getMessages();
        foreach($g["messages"] as $key => $message) {
            if(substr( $key, 0, strlen($id) ) === $id ) {
                $i++;
            }
        }

        return $i;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_extension';
    }
}
```

As you can see above, it calculates the number of $id occurrences in the translation catalogue. Translator takes care of locale, loading the appropiate catalogue and so on. It also caches results which is really good in terms of performance.

Register the service injecting the translator and registering as a twig extension:

```
services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\TransLengthExtension
        arguments: 
            - "@translator"
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now, in your template:

```
{% set end = 'termsAndConditions.paragraph'|translength %}
{% for i in range(1,end) -%}
   <p>{{('termsAndConditions.paragraph.'~i)|trans}}</p>
{%- endfor %}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its very close, but the problem is, i don't know the total, hence the `..n` & length.

Comment: This is the error I get `Variable "termsAndConditions" does not exist`

Comment: Not at my computer at the moment, will check in a few hours. I had a quick look at your update, it looks really good & detailed. Thank you. I will try it in a few hours :)

Comment: Works GREAT! I might writes some tests & put it on Github. If I do what is your Github Account Name so I can give you credit? Thanks again I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @EddieJaoude Thanks dude! Glad it works :) my name in Github is acontell too :)

Comment: Thanks. Bundle created & your name in the Credits section in the README https://github.com/eddiejaoude/symfony-translation-twig-collection-bundle

Comment: I just have 1 failing Spec test, any thoughts welcome https://github.com/eddiejaoude/symfony-translation-twig-collection-bundle/issues/1

Comment: @EddieJaoude Hi there, the problem is that you're using an object of type [LoggingTranslator](https://github.com/symfony/Translation/blob/master/LoggingTranslator.php) (that doesn't have the method getMessages). I'm injecting in the service an object of type [Translator](https://github.com/symfony/Translation/blob/master/Translator.php) (which does). Hope it helps. BTW, Thanks for mentioning me :)

Comment: Thank you again, that fixed the test, it was a long day yesterday :(. But when I do get_class in the construct of the extension class, I get Symfony\Component\Translation\LoggingTranslator which seems odd? The service is definitely "@translator"

Comment: Ignore that, i should type hint with the interface. I will update now :)

Comment: There was one error: `$g["messages"]` should be replaced with `$q[$domain]`. I have also [extended your version](http://pastebin.com/LCbG2AaU), because I have subkeys (faq.0.question, faq.0.answer, faq.1.question…)

Answer (score -1):

There's a twig filter for this - [keys](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/keys.html)

```
{% for keyname in yml_tree_nodes|keys %}
```